Отправка команд на Arduino через Python
Отправляю команду на рутина для выставления всех сервоприводов в положение 90 градусов, ответа от устройства никакого. До этого писал на Arduno IDE всё работало.
import time
import datetime

from Project.Station.Connection.close import close_connection
from Project.Station.Connection.establishing import establishing_connection


def station_calibration():
    connection = establishing_connection()

    left_servos = [30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
    right_servos = [31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41]

    for servo in right_servos:
        command = f"#{servo}P1500T1000\n"
        connection.write(command.encode())
        print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Отправлена команда: {command.strip()}")

    for servo in left_servos:
        command = f"#{servo}P1500T1000\n"
        connection.write(command.encode())
        print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Отправлена команда: {command.strip()}")

    time.sleep(2)

    close_connection(connection)


Подключение к ардуино срабатывает корректно, сами функции подключения и закрытия соединения использую

Использую давно, работают без нареканий.
